# Easy way to run Java project with different (and large) sets of additional classpath entries on each run

Tags: java, jar, classpath

Java project packed in jar perfectly runs with `java -cp some.jar some.package.Main`

Additional dependencies (project is about processing sources and requires dependencies for those to be on the classpath) can be provided by

`java -cp "some.jar;some/more.jar" some.package.Main` (works fine under Windows in my case)

But dependencies listing (all being in different folders) can easily exceed 40k characters, which makes me look for some other way to set it. Main criteria is ease of use (which executing 40k char long command doesn't have, even if it were possible under Windows), especially in terms of running with different sets of those (thus making changes to project jar is undesirable.

Comment: What is the scenario? I have not seen a need for a highly dynamic classpath before.

Comment: In your batch/cmd script, you could read in the classpath from a text file, or do a recursive directory search. May not be ideal and doesn't shorten the resulting command, but shortens the content manually entered into the script.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Third party plugins would be an example of this requirement, which is pretty common in programs now.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Original project is about processing sources and it requires dependencies for those to be on the classpath. Larger and more complex input requires more dependencies. Processing whole another project at once will take the whole classpath of another project as a part of execution classpath.

Comment: have you tried some/dir/*.jar? this is non-recursive but enables a short tidbit to read multiple sources.

Comment: @Wayne won't save much, unfortunately, jars with dependencies are mostly in different folders

Comment: @OlegSavelyev What about a custom Classloader or dynamic classpath modification at runtime (changes to the sources for the default Classloader at runtime)? Also, you could flatten the folders, if you jar/zip everything, you shouldn't need more than 1 folder - rename jars if needed to avoid conflicting names.

Comment: Source processing of jars _on the classpath_? This sounds strange. Per you would like to explain more? In any case, will the project jars not potentially conflict with the jars of the application?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen to simplify example, let's say original project wants to call `Class.forName` for some external classes, and it expects both them and their dependencies to be on classpath.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen conflicts may be an issue, but out of our scope for this moment.

Comment: @Wayne, I was hoping for some simple solution that I missed, before considering custom classloader. Dynamic classpath modification sounds tempting though.

Comment: @OlegSavelyev Flattening the dependencies folder is probably your best bet and the easiest tbh. If you're looking for an educational experience though, then dynamic modification is probably what you'd be looking for.

Comment: If you can use maven for this, you can have a tiny maven project for each configuration and use `mvn exec:java` to invoke. See https://github.com/ravn/dagger2-hello-world/ for a tiny example.